# com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/SchemaHandler.php on line 730

Tags: joomla, php, civicrm-home

**Do you have any information about the solution of the error found in the image?**

Joomla Version: 3.7.4
CiviCRM Version: 4.7.22

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried clearing cache? And clearing Expired Cache? I had the same error, cleared cache/expired cache and the message went away.
Also have you done the indices fix?

I found this to be useful
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21203